# Check if the content only starts with something

Tags: python, discord.py

I just began with `commands.bot` but got some experience in it.

So what I want to do is to say; If the message content only starts with the command, then do this and this.

Example thought:

```
@bot.command(name="verify", aliases="v", startswith=True)
async def verify(ctx):
    await ...
```

EDIT: I know how `.startswith()` works, my question is especially about `commands.bot` because (I think) the commands are only getting called when the whole message is only the command and my question is if there is a possibility to say that it only takes the start of the message or checks if it's in the message or something like this

Comment: What is your question? Please edit your post and add a clearly formulated question.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: This is a really great question, I even wrote the answer though, but sadly SO is not a "code it for me" type of site, please add your approaches, why they doesn't work, what's the current output, what's the expected output...

Comment: I got code and need help for this, so what exactly is the Porblem @ŁukaszKwieciński? I just need to know how it works or if it is possible, not a coding service

Comment: It is possible, but the code you provided s not even remotely close to the answer you’re looking for, I wouldn’t even name your code an ***approach***. Feel free to edit the question/ask a new one when you’ve actually done some research, SO is supposed to be the last place in your process of finding an answer.

Comment: Man I searched half an hour in the internet who do you think I am?? I got no clue how to do this without editing the discord.py module, so why should I ask here if I got a clue??